# Choose build configuration for referenced subproject

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, xcode

I have an iPhone project which references a framework as a subproject.

The framework has the following configurations:

- Debug
- Release

My app has the following configurations:

- Debug
- Release
- Distribution-AdHoc
- Distribution-AppStore

I would like the framework to be built with different configurations, depending on the app configuration:

- Debug -> Debug
- Release -> Release
- Distribution-AdHoc -> Release
- Distribution-AppStore -> Release

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the <strike>[Xcode Build System Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeBuildSystem/000-Introduction/Introduction.html)</strike>
Start with the section on Build Configurations.

**Edit:**

Since the link is dead, here is a [snapshot](http://web.archive.org/web/20100806201502/http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeBuildSystem/000-Introduction/Introduction.html) from webarchive.

Comment: Downvote due to simple link w/o any explanation.  It's good form on SO (at least I've read in meta) to include a brief explanation when linking, such that if the link goes dead (as this one did), the person still has a chance to find the information.